# How can I use different Xcode versions for different branches (or latest Xcode with different Clang versions)?

Tags: c++, xcode, clang

We compile different branches of our project with different versions of Xcode, because it has different versions of the c++ compiler "clang" built-in. And a new compiler not only means new features, but unfortunately also new compiler bugs (hence new workarounds). So we want to **keep the compiler once we branched** a stable version of our project, but **always use the latest compiler for the trunk**.

Installing several Xcode versions is easy: We just add the Version number to the name and so we get:

```
/Applications/Xcode9
/Applications/Xcode10
/Applications/Xcode11
```

For the integration server and other scripts the required version can easily be picked and started with

```
xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode10.app
xcodebuild -project myproj.xcodeproj build
```

But for working on the different branches with Xcode as graphical IDE this proves to be quite a problem:

- Unlike Visual Studio Solutions (.sln and .vcxproj), Xcode Projects (.xcproj) don't support the specification of an IDE version they open in.
- Different versions of Xcode don't play well together and seem to overwrite each others settings and caches (e.g. which projects/windows that were open, and even build status).

My last hope of solving this is to **always use the latest Xcode** IDE, but let it **use an earlier compiler version**.

There seems to be a project setting under *Build Options* for this, called *Compiler for C/C++/Objective-C* (`GCC_VERSION` when set via `.xcconfig`) with the standard value *Default Compiler (Apple Clang)* (`com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0`).

However, I was not able to find another valid value that I could use there. So far, I have tried [clang version number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode#Xcode_7.0_-_11.x_(since_Free_On-Device_Development)) and path to the clang executable (e.g. `/Applications/Xcode10.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang`). Xcode always says *Unsupported Compiler*.

So what is the correct way to specify another compiler version in Xcode? Or do you know another approach to solve the original problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to use an older clang version in latest IDE. This example works for using the *Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.2)* in the Xcode 11.3:

In the `.xcconfig` file (Menu->File->New->File, "Configuration Settings File"), the compiler paths can be set explicitly with

```
CC = /Applications/Xcode10.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
CPLUSPLUS = /Applications/Xcode10.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
```

But this is not enough: The system header files of a newer Xcode installation are sometimes incompatible with the old compiler. We need to set the roots for these files accordingly

```
OTHER_CFLAGS = -isysroot /Applications/Xcode10.app/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk
```